# how to extract numeric values from input string ? c++

Tags: c++, string

I need to get all the numbers (double) from a string and write them into an array.

**Example**

String: blabla2bla 123,12 bla bla 99 bla bla 3,1415bla bla

Array: **[2] [123,12] [99] [3,1415]**

I'm trying to do with *strtod* but do not quite understand how it works.

```
double d;
int leng;
string v;
char *end=(char*)s.c_str();
size_t i=0,k=0;
char buf[20];
while(1)
{
    d=strtod(s.c_str(),&end);
    cout<<d<<endl;
    if(d==NULL) break;
    sprintf(buf,"%f",d);
    v=(const char*)buf;
    leng=v.length();
    k=s.find(v,i)+1;
    s.erase(k,leng);
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If it is, show some code to solve the problem. You will get help sooner when you show that you have at least tried to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for information on how use SO and post **questions**.

Comment: You should try to paste code and attempt yourself, we do not do homework for you...however here is a hint use strtok then check the strings...to learn more google is your friend..If you still can't manage paste your code and people will help :)

Comment: How would you parse "xx123,456,789xx"?

Comment: This should not be. But if it does not matter 123,456 789 or 123 456.789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the format of the input in advance, you can use [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Comment: Question is tagged as C++, not C.

Comment: "sscanf" is the lazy/easy/most-c-like approach to simple input string parsing. You'll need to provide additional information or samples of your code for more detailed help: whether you are using std::strings or character arrays will be a significant factor, whether you are using c-like C++ will affect which types of functions you would use (strchr/strpbrk/strtok vs the C++ std::string member function equivalents)

Answer (score 0):

If the input is unknown (contrary to what ksfone's answer assumes), I think the easiest way would be to process each character one at a time with a combination of  [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) and a check for comma's after a number sequence.  The numbers can then be placed in an array as they are found.

Comment: Yeah, unedited, the post made it looked like a good candidate for sscanf.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach (untested, but should work)

The idea is to read things, and when they are not of the right datatype simply consume them and continue to read:

```
vector<double> l;

// loop will end wh1en stream is exhausted
while (cin) {
    double x;
    // while we read a double, add it to our list
    while (cin >> x) {
        l.push_back(x);
    }

    // entered a fail state
    cin.clear();
    // need to at least read a character
    cin.get();
}
```